# MS graph: no post data in notification

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I've been successfully creating a subscription like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54199766/microsoft-graph-api-subscription-notification-request-fail-issue):

```
object(Microsoft\Graph\Model\Subscription)#260 (1) {
  ["_propDict":protected] => array(16) {
    ["@odata.context"] => string(64) "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity"
    ["id"] => string(36) "8d3ec209-71c0-49c8-bdae-686ff5fc5cba"
    ["resource"] => string(42) "/users/jon.doe@example.com/events"
    ["applicationId"] => string(36) "0bb2b0ba-1770-42c3-8259-9609e15aad96"
    ["changeType"] => string(15) "created,updated"
    ["clientState"] => string(17) "SecretClientState"
    ["notificationUrl"] => string(69) "https://example.com/notif.php"
    ["notificationQueryOptions"] => NULL
    ["lifecycleNotificationUrl"] => NULL
    ["expirationDateTime"] => string(20) "2022-05-03T10:18:21Z"
    ["creatorId"] => string(36) "f5db159d-98a2-44b4-8d99-e619f0f60d90"
    ["includeResourceData"] => NULL
    ["latestSupportedTlsVersion"] => string(4) "v1_2"
    ["encryptionCertificate"] => NULL
    ["encryptionCertificateId"] => NULL
    ["notificationUrlAppId"] => NULL
  }
}
```

and I'm also getting a request to my end point when I change an event, but unfortunately it's empty, no post data as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/webhooks#change-notification-example). I can send post data to the url manually and it arrives fine. I could work around this (I'm not getting event resource data in the 1.0 api anyway) by including clientState, resource etc in the GET data in my notification url, but I'm wondering why graph doesn't send me any data.

Comment: The example in the documentation that you linked to shows JSON - so they are probably also sending this _as_ JSON, which means PHP will not populate $_POST, which I assume you tried to use to receive the data? In that case, see [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18866571/1427878)

Comment: what the heck, I didn't even know you could send/receive data like that, thank you!